# Encoding FBO textures to H.264 video directly on GPU

Tags: opengl, cuda, opencl, gpgpu, video-encoding

I am planning to write an app in which I need an ability to encode video from a given image sequence that comes from an FBO attached texture.I want to leverage the strength of GPU parallelism and do it all maximum "server side".So I found NVidia has an [SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-codec-libraries) which encodes video using CUDA , but after reading the SDK [white paper](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/3_Imaging/cudaEncode/doc/nvcuvenc.pdf) it is still not clear to me if it's possible to send  an FBO texture as the image frame source for the NVCUVENC (encoder) without leaving GPU.I believe that uploading images from CPU adds huge overhead to the encoding process because if I can't fetch FBO texture directly on GPU side , it means I have to read its pixels to CPU and then send them again to GPU for encoding.
So I have basically 2 questions:

1. Do [NVIDIA CODEC Libraries](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-codec-libraries) allow doing what I want?
2. If not ,can it be done with other GPGPU SDKs like OpenCL or even
   OpenGL 4.3 compute shaders?

Anything related to DirectX or other windows related stuff can't be taken into account as I need it for Linux.Also I use NVidia hardware only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely transfer OpenGL generated images into the CUDA Codec Library. Have a look at the CUDA API reference. Of most interest for you are *Texture Reference Management* and *Graphics Interoperability*. The basic idea is, that CUDA allows you to get a device side memory mapping of a texture object, which you can pass as image source to the encoder.

Comment: Is there any alternative to that, in particular staying on OpenGL, which with compute shaders can basically do whatever cuda can do (libraries aside)?

Comment: @Paul: Not really. The h264 encoder of NVidia GPUs is a dedicated part of silicon on the GPUs and not a shader program running. So you'll always have to use some vendor specific API for this. Either through a (hypothetical) OpenGL extension or through a sidekick API like CUDA.